# What are the consequences of Shor's code being degenerate?

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code

I read that Shor's code is degenerate and, as consequence, an error $\sigma_{1}^z - \sigma_{2}^z$ annihilates codewords.

However, I also read that one can assume such kind of error to never occur, as not being part of the Pauli group.

Hence, I don't understand where is the problem on a code being degenerate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is particularly a *problem* with a code being degenerate. It's just important to know if a code is degenerate because it influences some of its properties. For example, some things like the Quantum Hamming Bound only apply to non-degenerate codes. It might also make decoding/error correction less obvious because there's not a one-to-one mapping between the errors that occur and error syndromes. As I say, this isn't actually a problem. It's more just a flag that says "be careful".